# "Cannot access uninitialized variable." in class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have two very simple classes in my Javascript code:

```
class Renderable{
    toHTML(){
        return '';
    }
}


class Intro extends Renderable{
    constructor(title, pretitle, backgroundImage){
        debugger;
        this.title = title;
        this.pretitle = pretitle;
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }
    [...]
}
```

The code is *in order* this way, so there shouldn't be any hoisting issues. However, when I load my web page I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable.` at the line `this.title = title;` in the constructor. When I break on the debugger, I see that `this` is indeed `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using 'this' in derived class constructor" which should point you into the right direction.

Comment: @str yeah, just figured it out. the tutorial that I was following was plain wrong, with examples of derived classes that don't call super at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `super()` in your child class, as [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super): "When used in a constructor, the super keyword appears alone and must be used **before the this keyword is used**."

```js
class Renderable{
    toHTML(){
        return '';
    }
}


class Intro extends Renderable{
    constructor(title, pretitle, backgroundImage){
        super()
        this.title = title;
        this.pretitle = pretitle;
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }
}
const intro = new Intro('title', 'pretitle', 'bg.jpg')
alert(intro.title)
```

Comment: yeah, that was it. I was checking some docs from https://javascript.info/class-inheritance and it didn't have constructors of derived classes that explicitly call super, so I thought it wasn't needed. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line

```
class Intro extends Renderable{
    constructor(title, pretitle, backgroundImage){
        super(); // Whenever you extend a class you have to call parent constructor first
        this.title = title;
        this.pretitle = pretitle;
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }
    [...]
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super),
When used in a constructor, the super keyword appears alone and must be used before the this keyword is used. The super keyword can also be used to call functions on a parent object.
You can read [this](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/super-and-extends-in-javascript-es6-understanding-the-tough-parts-6120372d3420) article, to get better idea.